# Nontrivial integer solution of simple cubic equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there any nontrivial (except (0,0)) integer solution of the following equation?

$a^3+b^3-(a+b)^3+a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2=0$

Comment: yes deleted....

Comment: The only non-zero solutions with $-1000<a<b<1000$ is $a,b = 1,1$ and $a,b = -2,1$.

Comment: @User1917328: The equation is equivalent to $a (a + b) (-2 + 3 b) = 2 b^2$, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

We can rewrite it as
$$ab(3a+3b+2)=2(a+b)^2.$$
Suppose wlog $s=a+b>0$. If $|a|$ or $|b|\geq2$, we have
$$|ab|\geq|a|+|b|\geq a+b$$
and hence
$$2s^2=|ab(3a+3b+2)|\geq|ab|\cdot(|3a+3b|-2)\geq3(a+b)^2-2(a+b)=3s^2-2s.$$
From $s^2-2s\leq0$ it follows that $s\leq2$. Looking back to the first equation we see that $a,b\mid8$.

This means it suffices to check $|a|,|b|\leq8$. The only solutions are $(0,0),(1,1),(1,-2),(-2,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to $a (a + b) (-2 + 3 b) = 2 b^2$ , so 
$$9\frac{2 b^2}{3b-2}=9\left({2 b\over 3}+{8\over 9 (3 b-2)}+{4\over 9}\right) $$must be an integer, hence $3b-2\mid 8$ or $2b^2=0$. $b\in \{-8, -2, 1, 4\}$ since we are looking for non-trivial solutions.
Then we check that only $b=-2$ and $b=1$ leads to $\dfrac{2 b^2}{3b-2}$ to be an integer, so we only need to find such a that
$$\left[\begin{array}{ll}a(a-2)=-1,&b=-2\\a(a+1)=2,&b=1\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3=(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+2(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
and so
$$3ab(a+b)=2(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Now let the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ be $g$, and let $a=gx$ and $b=gy$ for some integers $x$ and $y$.

Now in the original equation, we see that $(a+b)$ is a factor of each term on the left hand side except for $a^2+b^2$, and so we must have that
$$(a+b)\mid(a^2+b^2)$$
But then from $(a+b)\mid(a+b)^2$, we get that
$$(a+b)\mid 2ab$$
Plugging in $a=gx$ and $b=gy$ gives us
$$g(x+y)\mid 2g^2xy$$
Since $(x+y)$ and $xy$ are relatively prime, we get that $(x+y)\mid 2g$. Let $2g = k(x+y)$. Then we have that
$$a=\frac{kx(x+y)}{2}\quad\text{ and }\quad b=\frac{ky(x+y)}{2}$$
For some integer $k$, and relatively prime integers $x$ and $y$.

We thus must solve
$$\frac{3k^2xy(x+y)^2}{4}\cdot\frac{k(x+y)^2}{2}=2\left(\frac{k^2(x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2}{4}+\frac{k^2xy(x+y)^2}{4}\right)$$
which (under the assumption that $(a,b)\neq (0,0)$) simplifies to
$$3kxy(x+y)^2 = 4(x^2+xy+y^2)$$
$x$ divides the left hand side, and so $x$ divides $4y^2$. Since $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, $x \mid 4$. Similarly, $y \mid 4$.

$x$ and $y$ can't both be even, so one of them is equal to $\pm 1$. Additionally, the equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, and $(x,y)$ is a solution iff $(-x, -y)$ is, so we can assume without loss of generality that $y=1$. Then the equation becomes
$$3kx(x+1)^2=4(x^2+x+1)$$
Considering this $\mod 3$ and remembering that $x\mid 4$, we see that we only need to check $x \in \{-2, 1, 4\}$.

If $x = -2$ then we have $-6k=12$ and so $k=-2$. This gives us $a=-2$ and $b=1$.

If $x=1$ then we get $12k=12$, which gives us $k=1$ and so $a=b=1$.

If $x=4$, then we get $300k=84$. In this case, $k$ is not an integer, and so we have no solutions.

We see that all solutions to the equation are given by $(a,b)\in\{(-2,1),(0,0), (1,1), (1,-2)\}$